# How to give input to linux mail program with c++?

Tags: c++, linux, email

On my Linux server I have installed a mail server which stores unread mails in one mbox file and those that have been read in the other file.

I have a c++ program that reads incoming mails automatically, but it only reads the mbox file and doesn't move mails to the "**read**" file and I don't want to do it in my c++ program as it could, in theory, overwrite any new incoming mails.

Manually this is done by running the "`mail`" command in the Linux terminal, then inputting the number of a mail (oldest unread one is always 1 and this is the one I want to mark as read) and exiting the mail program by inputting q.

I have figured out that I can run "mail" in my program with `System("mail");`, but I can't figure out how to input the "1" and the "q"  as kSystem("1"); doesn't have the desired effect, so that's the main part of the question.

Alternatively, if there is a better way to move mails to the "read" file please share it with me.

Comment: replace the command `"mail"` by `"echo -e 1\\nq | mail"` or `"(echo 1; echo q) | mail"` if you do not have the option `-e`. You can also use `popen` rather than `system` to get the output

Comment: Thank you for the help, also in the meantime I have found that System("echo p | mail") does what I needed too.

Comment: Use [procmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) to walk the mbox and pass each mail to your program separately.